# silverlight duplex communicates with self-hosted wcf services cross-domain problem

Tags: silverlight, wcf

I have a silverlight4 application which needs to call and be called back the wcf services self-hosted in a local windows-form application.
I wanna use the net.tcp protocal to achieve the duplex communication but encounter cross-domain problem.
It's easy to find solutions of the cross-domain problem but most of them is for the IIS-hosted WCF services.How to solve the cross-domain problem of a **net.tcp** WCF Service which is **self hosted** in a local windows-form application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is listed at the blog post at [Enabling cross-domain calls for SL apps on self-hosted TCP services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2010/07/25/enabling-cross-domain-calls-for-sl-apps-on-self-hosted-tcp-services.aspx). Basically, if you have IIS installed on the machine you simlpy drop the cross-domain file for TCP in the root. If not, you can use the same self-hosted WCF service to serve the cross-domain file at port 80.